# Restore SQL Server backup from varbinary(max) variable backup file

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I am trying to create a procedure that should restore a backup of the database. I would like to pass the backup file through a varbinary (max) type parameter.

It is possible? I could not find any reference to that.

I need to perform this task because the backup file will not be on the server, it will be on a client machine.

I need to call this procedure on code (C#).

**EDIT**

Today, I've the following code that creates and returns the backup file:

```
DECLARE @MdfFilePath AS VARCHAR(MAX),
        @BackupFileName AS VARCHAR(MAX),
        @DbName AS VARCHAR(MAX) = DB_NAME()
SELECT 
    @MdfFilePath = physical_name 
FROM 
    sys.master_files 
WHERE 
    database_id = DB_ID(@DbName)

SELECT @BackupFileName = LEFT(@MdfFilePath,LEN(@MdfFilePath) - charindex('\',reverse(@MdfFilePath),1) + 1) + @DbName +'_' + 
        REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), GETDATE(), 121), ':',  '-') + '.bak'

BACKUP DATABASE @DbName
TO DISK = @BackupFileName
WITH INIT   


DECLARE @SQL AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK ''' + @BackupFileName + ''', SINGLE_BLOB) rs'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
```

I need a feature that allow me to pass the backup file back to the server, next, restore it.

Comment: No, as far as I know, the file has to **physically exist** on disk, either on the server's own internal disks, or a network location (specified via a UNC path) that the server (and the server process' account) have access to. You cannot just pass a `varbinary(max)` variable with the backup. Also: that variable would be limited to **2 GB**, and your database backup can *easily* outgrow that limit

Comment: If you use a c# app to call this procedure, you can pass the .bak file as a parameter, like an image or another document.

Comment: @mcNets Ok. How to restore a backup file from a varbinary(max) stream variable?

Comment: use the c# app to save the file on disk and pass its name to the restore script as a parameter again

Comment: Also, if the database containing the backups goes down you can't restore from a backup :)

Comment: About the size limit that @marc_s told? Save file on disk in a client machine? Sql server does not allow me to restore backups from local machine disk, unless using unc path.

Comment: @marc_s, post your comment as answer please.

Comment: The share on the local machine may have to be made public or visible to the service account that is running SQL server on the server.  Also note that compressed backups may save you considerable time reading and writing the backup file over the network.  Your overall concept with the FILESTREAM location on the server would be an interesting idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - SQL Server Engine must be able to "see" the physical file to be restored. The best you can achieve is to set your client PC backup location as a shared drive that the SQL Server Service host Server can map to.